# Invalid drivers aren't shown and can't be deleted

Tags: drivers, command-line

I have following problem.

With the minecraft rig works everything fine (thomas rig) but when I open the console there are displayed invalid drivers of already deleted objects.
How can I delete them? Even if select everything in the outliner and then go to the driver editor these aren't displayed. Therefore I can't delete them.
So how can I delete them?
I am really struggling with that.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Remove, since removed shape-key drivers.**

From pic in question appears they are shape key drivers, which remain if a keyblock is removed, renamed (To reproduce, add a shapekey "Key 1", give it a driver, delete the shapekey. Then add a new key, and since its name is "Key 1" bingo it has a driver... )

Code to remove invalid path shape key drivers.

```
import bpy

for sk in bpy.data.shape_keys:
    if not sk.animation_data:
        continue
    bung_drivers = []
    # find bung drivers
    for d in sk.animation_data.drivers:
        try:
            sk.path_resolve(d.data_path)
        except ValueError:
            bung_drivers.append(d)
    # remove bung drivers
    while bung_drivers:
        sk.animation_data.drivers.remove(
                bung_drivers.pop()
                )
```

**Generic, for all ID types**

Loop over all ID types in the data of the blend and remove any driver whose path does not resolve.

```
import bpy
from bpy import data
from bpy.types import bpy_prop_collection

colls = [
    p for p in dir(data)
    if isinstance(getattr(data, p), bpy_prop_collection)
    ]

for p in colls:
    for ob in getattr(data, p, []):
        ad = getattr(ob, "animation_data", None)
        if not ad:
            continue
        bung_drivers = []
        # find bung drivers
        for d in ad.drivers:
            try:
                ob.path_resolve(d.data_path)
            except ValueError:
                bung_drivers.append(d)
        # remove bung drivers
        while bung_drivers:
            ad.drivers.remove(
                    bung_drivers.pop()
                    )
```

Comment: Hello batFinger, 
thanks for the help! 
I now have run the code and most of the errors are gone now. But there are still some errors about bone constraints like this:

`WARN (bke.anim_sys): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_291\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\anim_sys.c:2926 BKE_animsys_eval_driver: invalid driver - pose.bones["L.Leg_knee.009"].constraints["Copy Rotation"].mute[0]`

and how would i remove these then?
thanks in advance :D

Comment: Back up first. Try replacing `bpy.data.shape_keys` with `bpy.data.objects`.  (In theory "should" be able to roll this over all `bpy.data` collections)

Comment: This is awesome ! The error messages also pop up when you delete a modifier with drivers without deleting its drivers first and it's a pain in the *** to look for when you have a lot of objects

Comment: I have tried it and it works perfectly for me! Every error is now gone. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Open the *Driver Editor* window, press <kbd>Right Click</kbd>, and on the menu select *Delete all Invalid Drivers*.

This will solve your problem.